# Alertdialog shows background three times on old devices

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to make a dialog with a custom style.
On android 5 it works:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7zsG.png

But on older devices this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIXuR.png

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/PopupDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

background_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#7b8f8a"/>
</shape>
```

I Tried many things but nothing seems to work.